# add legend to ggmap for gemo_polygon data

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have used two data sets (MR + MRTag) to plot points onto a ggmap.

```
MR
detect_date        Latitude      Longitude    species
12/04/2016 11:08    -6.6524      71.3475      Manta Ray
12/04/2016 11:09    -6.6524      71.3475      Manta Ray
12/04/2016 11:10    -6.6524      71.3475      Manta Ray
16/04/2016 21:27    -6.6524      71.3475      Manta Ray

MRTag
species    taggingdate   deploy_lat  deploy_lon
Manta Ray   3/24/2016   -5.4191      71.83855
Manta Ray   02/05/2013  -5.2568      71.65768333
Manta Ray   02/07/2013  -5.33448     71.9812
Manta Ray   02/08/2013  -5.3046      71.94231667
```

I then used this code to plot the data onto the map and produced a legend for the map.

```
 MR_plot <- ggmap(MR_map) + 
 geom_point(data = MR, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude,
                        color = 'detect', shape = 'detect', fill = 
                        'detect'), size = 1) +
 geom_point(data = MRTag, aes(x = deploy_lon, y = deploy_lat,
                           color = 'tag', shape = 'tag', fill = 
                          'tag')) +
 xlab("Longitude") + 
 ylab("Latitude") +
 scale_color_manual(name = 'legend', values = c(detect = 'white', tag 
                    = '#00FF00'), 
                   labels = c("Detections", "Tagging Locations")) +
 scale_fill_manual(name = 'legend', values = c(detect = NA, tag = 
                   '#00FF00'),
                   labels = c("Detections", "Tagging Locations")) +
 scale_shape_manual(name = 'legend', values = c(detect = 1, tag = 
                    25),
                    labels = c("Detections", "Tagging Locations")) +
 theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
 theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(),legend.box.margin = 
 margin(6, 6, 6, 6)) +
 theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "#003399", colour = "black"))
```

Which produces this plot [image: plot 1]

Then I calculated some distribution data and plotted this onto the existing map.

```
MR_plot +
  geom_polygon(data= extent_KUD, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               fill = "white", color = "white", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_polygon(data = core_KUD, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group), 
               fill = "red", alpha = 0.2, color = "red") +
  ggtitle("Kernel utilisation distributions for manta rays 2015-18")
```

And produced this plot

[image: plot2]

I then tried to create another legend by moving colour and fill options into the aes () and using scale_x_manual functions using this code;

```
MR_plot +
  geom_polygon(data= extent_KUD, 
           aes(x = long, y = lat, group = 'extent', color = 'extent', 
               fill = 'extent'), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_polygon(data = core_KUD, 
           aes(x = long, y = lat, group = 'core', color = 'core', 
               fill = 'core'), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(name = 'legend', values = c(extent = 'white', 
                     tag = 'red'),
                     labels = c("Extent", "Core")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = 'legend', values = c(extent = 'white', 
                    core= 'red'),
                    labels = c("Extent", "Core")) +
  ggtitle("Kernel utilisation distributions for blacktip reef sharks 
  2014-17")
```

However, I get an error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 2 provided.

What is the best way of adding a legend for the extent and core polygons onto the existing graph?

Comment: Can you post your data and all the code you used for this plot? What do you want in the legend: fill, color, shape, etc? You haven't included code that would generate a legend for us to help debug

Comment: I've updated my question to be moe detailed

Comment: It looks like at least part of your issue could be solved by making a single long-shaped dataframe from the two dataframes. That lets you make a single call to `geom_polygon` and assign whatever variable you have to differentiate (maybe a column with possible values "extent" or "core"?) to color and/or fill. You shouldn't have to give static values to color or fill in your `aes`.

Comment: I'm not overly familar with the techniques, and pretty new to R and not quite sure how to do that but I will look into it thank you.

Comment: Cool, I'd recommend [this tutorial](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) on tidy data